# Default string/text assignment not working in ASP textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a relatively simple problem I have not been able to find the solution to.

I have 3 text boxes for user input quantities, 3 corresponding text boxes that display the total, which is quantity * price, and one final texbox that displays the total of the 3 calculated costs.

I have this working, but along the way I was unable to assign a default value to the textboxes.  Here is my code for one of the 3 textboxes:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity3" runat="server" CssClass="textboxGeneral"
     AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="tbQuantity3_TextChanged" Text="1"> 
    </asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender
         ID="ftbeQuantity3"
         TargetControlID="tbQuantity3"
         runat="server"
         FilterType="Numbers, Custom"
         ValidChars=".">
    </ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</td>
```

Originally, I was trying to set default values of 0 so that the textboxes would not be null and the total of the 3 costs could be calculated if the user had not entered 3 quantities.  I realized a better solution was to check for null values in the code behind, but I would still also like to be able to set default values of the textboxes and am not sure why the **Text="1"** property of the asp textbox is not working.

Comment: Try putting the text within the element, e.g. `<asp:TextBox>1</asp:textBox>`

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to try that.  It also appears to have no effect, though.  I changed the textbox to:
<asp:TextBox ID="tbComplicatedRecordCostsQuantity0" runat="server" CssClass="textboxGeneral"
                                    AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="tbComplicatedRecordCostsQuantity0_TextChanged" Text="1">1</asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a "ClearActiviityFields()" function running at different points that was setting the textbox back to blank.  The Text=1 was in fact working, it was just being undone before I got to that page.